# Prevent changes in group subscriptions

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk, google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

how can I prevent that a member of a group can change his group subscription?

https://support.google.com/groups/answer/9792489?hl=en

I want him to receive all group emails. he must not be able to select
"Digest", or "Abridged" or "No email" settings

I tried by API group settings
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/manage?hl=en
setting showInGroupDirectory as false, but users still see the group in the list

Answer (score 0):

Anything you try will fail because you have Groups Service enabled. You must ***disable*** Groups Service for your domain: https://support.google.com/a/answer/182442

Only then, you will have control on users with Groups Service ***disabled***
P.S: Any domain with Groups Service disabled will have them treated as mailing lists.